# dyld cache '/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h' not loaded: syscall to map cache into shared region failed

Tags: python-3.x, dyld

I'm getting this error when trying to use python 3. How can I solve this issue?

> dyld[2675]: dyld cache
> '/System/Library/dyld/dyld_shared_cache_x86_64h' not loaded: syscall
> to map cache into shared region failed dyld[2675]: Library not loaded:
> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
> Referenced from:
> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
> Reason: tried:
> '/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation'
> (no such file),
> '/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation'
> (no such file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like you've got multiple installations of Python 3 that may have carried over from a previous macOS upgrade. If you directly type `/usr/bin/python3` and don't get an error then this is likely an issue with a homebrew/macports/something else custom installation. You can type `which python3` to see what it would execute by default when just using `python3`, but the fix depends on what you've done to your system. Check [dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65878141) for more help.

Comment: `which python3` returns: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3. I guess that is a bad version. I have tried using /usr/bin/python3 to run my file but this gives an error that I don't have a package installed. When I run pip list the package is there.

Comment: It looks like you may have some incorrect mental models of how Python manages packages and how pathing works for shells in Unix-like OSes. I'd highly suggest spending some time learning a bit about that and how virtual environments work so that you can more effectively isolate your own projects from global packages or the system itself.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! The link to the other question explained what happened on my machine exactly (macOS -> updated to monterey and got a new version of python3). I have installed way too many python environments directly so deleting some of them from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It happened because the new macos installed a newer version of python3 and was not able to connect to the existing older version. I could solve it by looking under /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions and updating the pointed python3 version (as current) in my interpreter settings within pycharm ide.